# Call function in array php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

Complete newbie to programming :)

i am fiddling around with a WordPress theme and hit a roadblock.  If i put this in archive.php,

```
<?php 

if (is_category(array( 9, 13, 24,)) {
 echo 'Light is GREEN';
  }else {
 echo 'Light is RED}';
 ?>
```

That part works fine, when i go to category 9, 13, 24 i get "light is Green" and "light is red" for all other categories.

Now i have this function which gets the id's of categories from theme options where i need to echo "light is green"

```
function am_get_cat_layout_ids()
{

                global $am_option;
                $catnumend = $am_option['main']['category_onecolumn_hidden']-1;
                for($i=0; $i<$catnumend; $i++)
                {

                    $value = $am_option['main']['category_onecolumn_'.$i].',';


                }

                return $value;
}
```

if i echo $value instead of return, i get the category id's say 2, 15, 7, 34, fine but if i do this :

```
  <?php 

if (is_category(array(am_get_cat_layout_ids())) {
 echo 'Light is GREEN';
  }else {
 echo 'Light is RED}';
 ?>
```

its not working.

anything that can be done to make it work?

Thank you ,
Srik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function am_get_cat_layout_ids()
{
    global $am_option;
    $ret = array();
    $catnumend = $am_option['main']['category_onecolumn_hidden']-1;

    for($i=0; $i<$catnumend; $i++)
    {
            $ret[] = $am_option['main']['category_onecolumn_'.$i];
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

and

```
if (is_category(am_get_cat_layout_ids()) {
    echo 'Light is GREEN';
}else {
    echo 'Light is RED}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `am_get_cat_layout_ids()` function returns `2, 15, 7, 34,` then you should do:

```
if (is_category(explode(', ',trim(am_get_cat_layout_ids(),','))) {
 echo 'Light is GREEN';
  }else {
 echo 'Light is RED}';
```

Comment: That's definitely doing this backwards. Just build the array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What you have made is an array containing one string, which has comma-separated numbers. You want to build an array of numbers.

```
function am_get_cat_layout_ids()
{
    global $am_option;

    $ids = array(); // create array
    $catnumend = $am_option['main']['category_onecolumn_hidden']-1;

    for($i=0; $i<$catnumend; $i++)
    {
        $ids[] = $am_option['main']['category_onecolumn_'.$i]; // add value to array
    }
    return $ids; // return array
}
```

Your original code was the equivalent to this:

```
if (is_category(array( "9, 13, 24,")) {
```

Whereas this new code is the equivalent to the code at the beginning of the question:

```
if (is_category(am_get_cat_layout_ids()) {
```